# Android issue with programatically created buttons

Tags: android, android-view

Well im trying to get the text on each button, it displays the text correctly on each but when i try to print it, it shows the same text. The text of optionD

```
private void displayQuestion() {
            final ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++){
                Questions diaplayQuestion = questions.get(i);
                question.setText(diaplayQuestion.getQuestion());
                options.add(0, diaplayQuestion.getOptionA());
                options.add(1, diaplayQuestion.getOptionB());
                options.add(2, diaplayQuestion.getOptionC());
                options.add(3, diaplayQuestion.getOptionD());
                correctOption = diaplayQuestion.getCorrectOption();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++) {
                btn = new Button(GameplayActivity.this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 0);
                btn.setLayoutParams(params);
                btn.setText(options.get(i));
                btn.setId(i);
                linearLayout.addView(btn);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        System.out.println(view.getId());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store some information inside `View` use tags. From official docs:

> Unlike IDs, tags are not used to identify views. Tags are essentially an extra piece of information that can be associated with a view. They are most often used as a convenience to store data related to views in the views themselves rather than by putting them in a separate structure.

So in your case it'll be like this:

```
btn = new Button(GameplayActivity.this);
...
btn.setTag(options.get(i)); // I assume that value is String
...
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        System.out.println((String) view.getTag());
    }
});
```